# How to forward declare boost smart ptr?

Tags: c++, boost

This code fails to compile:

```
namespace boost
{
  template<class T> class scoped_ptr;
}

namespace FooNamespace
{

class FooClass
{
  boost::scoped_ptr<FooType> foo;
};

}
```

g++ says: `error: field ‘foo’ has incomplete type`

I thought it would be ok since I copied the scoped_ptr declaration over from the actual boost header file... What did I screw?

Note: The problem is not in `FooType`. I tried substituting it by `int` to no avail...

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forward declarations do not work if the size of the forward-declared type must be known. Since you're embedding an instance of `boost::scoped_ptr<T>` in `FooClass`, the size of that type must be known.

You could embed a pointer instead, but that probably would defeat the purpose of `scoped_ptr<T>` in the first place. However, it would compile:

```
class FooClass
{
    boost::scoped_ptr<FooType> *foo;
};
```

Comment: Oh, I see.
I guess I'll have to use `auto_ptr` then. I don't want to make users of my .h have to either include boost or support C++11 (yet)... :-/

Answer (score 6):

There are restrictions on what you can do with an incomplete type (that is, a type that's been declared but not defined); one thing you can't do is define a variable of that type. That's because the size has to be known, in this case in order to work out the layout of member variables within an object.

Things that you can do include using a pointer or reference to the type (as long as you don't dereference it), declaring a function with the type as an argument or return value, and declaring static or non-member variables of the type.